# Convert decimal numbers to time (hours:mins:secs) with lubridate

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have this vector:

```
numbers <- c(2.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.9, 0.6)
```

How, using `lubridate`, can I convert these decimal numbers to times (hours:mins:secs). So the output should be the following vector of class `Period`

```
(02:24:00, 00:42:00, 00:30:00, 00:12:00, 00:54:00, 00:36:00)
```

I have searched both stack overflow and the Google for an answer to this question. It might be that I'm using the wrong search terms, but I cannot find an answer.

Comment: Trim the unit and convert the decimal.

Comment: Try `format(as.POSIXct("2016-02-16 00:00:00") + 3600*numbers, '%H:%M:%S')`  (as the dupe link gives only a partial answer)